# Multi direction slider

Tags: jquery

I have set up a slider so that each time the next button is clicked the image will slide in from a different direction. e.g;
 First click slide from top
Second from left
third from top
forth from left e.t.c e.t.c.

So far I have the first three working correctly but after the fourth click the images slide in only from the side.

Here is what i have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var totalslides = '6';
        var slidenum = 0;
        var slidenext = 0;
        var slideType = '';
        $(function(){
            $('#gallery-next').data('counter',1);
            $('#gallery-next').click(function() {
               slidenum = parseInt($('#gallery-next').data('counter'));
               slidenext = slidenum+1
               slideType = $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').attr('class')
               slideType = slideType.split('-')[0]

               if (slideType =='') slideType='up';
               else slideType = 'right';
                //alert('Next slideType is: ' + slideType)
                //hide(slide) is a jQueryUI function, so ensure you include that lib
               $('#'+slidenext+'-slide').delay(605).show('slide',{direction:slideType}, 1000);
               $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').fadeOut(600);

               $('#'+slidenext+'-text').delay(731).fadeIn(1000);
               $('#'+slidenum+'-text').fadeOut(600);

               slidenum = slidenum % totalslides + 1;
               $('#gallery-next').data('counter',slidenum);

               console.log(slideType);
            });
        });
    </script>

<div id="slider">

            <section class="horizontal-gallery">
                <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="" id="1-slide"/>
                <p id="1-text" class="horizontal-gallery-text">This is the first image in the gallery </p>
            </section>

            <section class="vertical-gallery">
                <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_v1.jpg" class="picture2 init-hidden" id="2-slide"/>
                <p id="2-text" class="vertical-gallery-text init-hidden">This is the second image in the gallery, it should be sliding down</p>
            </section>

            <section class="horizontal-gallery">
                <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="picture3 init-hidden" id="3-slide"/>
                <p id="3-text" class="horizontal-gallery-text text-3 init-hidden">This is the third image in the gallery it should be sliding in from the side </p>
            </section>

            <section class="vertical-gallery">
                <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_v1.jpg" class="picture4 init-hidden" id="4-slide"/>
                <p id="4-text" class="vertical-gallery-text text-4 init-hidden">This is the fourth image in the gallery, it should be sliding down </p>
            </section>
```

http://luvly.co.nz/space/test/waikanae-beach-house.html

If somebody could figure out why it isn't working properly it would be much appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Here is an example of what is happening: http://luvly.co.nz/space/test/waikanae-beach-house.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (slideType =='') slideType='up';
else slideType = 'right';
```

The logic is not right here. `slideType` will only be null on the first time, then `slideType` will always exist, therefore always transitioning right.

Fix:

Use the **rel** attribute.

Replace the next lines:

```
slideType=$('#'+slidenum+'-slide').attr('class') 
slideType=slideType.split('-')[0]

if (slideType=='') slideType='up';
else slideType='right';
```

With the following code:

```
slideType = $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').attr('rel')
```

Then specify with the rel attribute whether you want it to be 'right' or 'up':

```
<img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="" id="1-slide" rel="up" />

...

<img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="" id="2-slide" rel="right" />
```

Comment: Any ideas on how i could go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `slideType` returns empty at first then non-empty from there on.

So, instead of:

```
if (slideType =='') slideType='up'; else slideType = 'right';
```

Do this for example:

```
var c = 0; //counter

$('#gallery-next').click(function() {
    // your code...
    slideType = c % 2 === 0 ? 'up' : 'right';
    c++;
    // your code...
});
```

I realize, you have a counter kept such as:

```
slidenum = parseInt($('#gallery-next').data('counter'));
```

I don't see any reason to keep the counter inside the jQuery `data` object. You should use a simple variable just like shown above.

Also, the value of `totalslides` is a string; it should be a **number**:

```
var totalslides = '6'; //should be 6
```

Better, don't make it a constant value bec. you will always need to edit the code when you add another slide. So get it dynamically:

```
var totalslides = $('#slider').children().length;
```